# consume custom binding oracle WFC web service with ruby / savon

Tags: ruby, oracle, web-services, ssl, savon

I am trying to consume a wfc web service with a non basicthttp binding with ruby and savon.

The provider of the WS implemented the oracle/wss11_username_token_with_message_protection_service_policy (which is described here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/soa/oracle-msft-interoperate-183511.html)

If I understand correctly this policy is expecting some sort of encryption (according to this http://blog.raastech.com/2012/08/owsm-security-errors.html) due to the non basic http binding

The WS described actually goes over ssl which may be the root of all evil due to me implementing it poorly.

Is even possible to consume a WFC WS with non basic http binding with savon?

My background is ruby and rails, yet I am new to WS (and savon) and ssl usage.

Now the provider of the WS does not give much of support. Actually their outing is that they only provide support for implementations in java or .net (is that even possible given that it’s a WS and thus platform independent?).

In an attempt to run the fairly simple code which is the following

```
require 'savon'
client = Savon.client do 

  wsdl      "https://apps.ika.gr/hospitalisationWSS_TEST-hospitalisationWSS_TEST-context-root/MainWSClassPort?WSDL"
  wsse_auth "ΥΥΥΥ", "ΧΧΧΧ"     # ALTERED
  wsse_timestamp true

  pretty_print_xml true
  log_level :debug

  ssl_verify_mode :none
  ssl_cert_file       "files/ika.cer"  # provided by WS provider
end


save_admission_hl7_msg = "MSH|^~\&|||||201310111112||ADT^A13^ADT_A13|2013000012113|P|2.6|||||||||66645678912345678945|^^^^^^^^^10000\nEVN|A13|201310101122|||nosiliapap\nPID\nPV1||I|||||||||||||||||2013000012111|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||2013000012113\n"

response = client.call(:save_admission_hl7,  
         :attributes => { :xmlns => "http://bean.intracom.com/" }, 
          :message => { :arg0 => {  :@xmlns=>'', :content! =>{ :hl7ADT =>     save_admission_hl7_msg     }    }  } )
end

puts response.body
```

Ι get the following output

```
D, [2013-12-04T08:21:20.445549 #3088] DEBUG -- : HTTPI GET request to apps.ika.gr (httpclient)
I, [2013-12-04T08:21:22.074643 #3088]  INFO -- : SOAP request: https://apps.ika.gr/hospitalisationWSS_TEST-hospitalisationWSS_TEST-context-root/MainWSClassPort
I, [2013-12-04T08:21:22.074643 #3088]  INFO -- : SOAPAction: "saveAdmissionHl7", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 1363
D, [2013-12-04T08:21:22.075643 #3088] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://bean.intracom.com/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
        <wsse:Username>YYYY</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXX</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-2">
        <wsu:Created>2013-12-04T06:21:22Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2013-12-04T06:22:22Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <tns:saveAdmissionHl7 xmlns="http://bean.intracom.com/">
      <arg0 xmlns="">
        <hl7ADT>MSH|^~&amp;|||||201310111112||ADT^A13^ADT_A13|2013000012113|P|2.6|||||||||66645678912345678945|^^^^^^^^^10000
EVN|A13|201310101122|||nosiliapap
PID
PV1||I|||||||||||||||||2013000012111|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||2013000012113
</hl7ADT>
      </arg0>
    </tns:saveAdmissionHl7>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>

D, [2013-12-04T08:21:22.076643 #3088] DEBUG -- : HTTPI POST request to apps.ika.gr (httpclient)
I, [2013-12-04T08:21:22.472665 #3088]  INFO -- : SOAP response (status 500)
D, [2013-12-04T08:21:22.473665 #3088] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:Fault xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <faultcode xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns0:FailedCheck</faultcode>
      <faultstring>FailedCheck : failure in security check</faultstring>
    </ns2:Fault>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

f:/rubystack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.3.0/lib/savon/response.rb:85:in `raise_soap_and_http_errors!': (ns0:FailedCheck) FailedCheck : failure in security check (Savon::SOAPFault)
        from f:/rubystack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.3.0/lib/savon/response.rb:14:in `initialize'
        from f:/rubystack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.3.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:64:in `new'
        from f:/rubystack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.3.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:64:in `create_response'
        from f:/rubystack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.3.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:55:in `call'
        from f:/rubystack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.3.0/lib/savon/client.rb:36:in `call'
        from eopyy.rb:82:in `<main>'
```

Now given my poor knowledge on WS's and SSL usage I cant figure out the error. 
Is it the SSL? Should I use ssl_ca_cert_file instead of ssl_cert_file ? (obviously I tried that already). Do I need to use a key file also?

The provider actually provides a .jks file (next to the above "ika.cer" certificate) but also mentions that it should be used only within a java implementation (an not a .net). I already unpacked the jks file and attempted to use its contained certificates and files, unsuccesfully.

Any help, clues, tips, greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you run in ssl_certify_mode :none you shouldn't need a certification file. As the setting suggests: no certification.

Comment: If you expect people to respond you should probably reduce your question to the necessary minimum. Most people are willing to help but don't like to understand other people's problem by reading their source code. So far I could consume all kind of WS with Ruby/Savon. My advice would be to use SoapUI in a first step to find a working solution. That would separate your WS from your Ruby problems. In a second step you can translate the pure WS solution into a Ruby solution. I'll happy to help.

Comment: thanx for your reply. I was under the impression that "none" only ignores locally the verification (and thus validity of the cert.) but still uses it for the connection. Anyway, i tried it, but it doesnt change a thing (same error). Yes you are perhaps right about my post's length. Even though my intention was the exact opposite (wanted to give the whole picture). Have you actually consumed an ssl using WFC WS with savon? Concerning SoapUI I already tried it, unsuccesfully. Meaning, when I give it the wsdl url, it simply crashes with a "failed to load url" (though the url opens in the browser)

Comment: furthermore, within my ruby script I can actually GET the wsdl (and display the actions via client.operations). The program crashes when I actually attempt to POST to it.

Comment: I dealt with WS hosted by IIS (*.svc) and TomCat/JAX-WS. Both "handrolled" out of the same description language. I don't known WFC is that Windows Foundation Class??, seems odd because on the other hand Oracle software is involved. That SoapUI crashes is a bad sign :-(. It worked for me in 95% of all cases. I personally haven't used WSSE, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: thanx for your reply Steffen. Yep thats what WFC stands for. For the time being I outsourced the development of the solution in java. I'll attempt to implement it in ruby afterwards. Will post it if succesfull.